# Trying to get Eclipse console view content

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jconsole

I'm trying to get Eclipse console view content for my Java Eclipse plugin by using the console class(`System.console()`) but I searched for it and found that while in the Eclipse IDE it always return null.

Is there a way to get the console content after compilation while working in the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does not use the `Console` class, it has a much more elaborate console system.

The Eclipse Console View can contain many consoles for output from different things (such as the last program run, SVN output, ....).

To see what consoles are available use the console manager:

```java
IConsoleManager manager = ConsolePlugin.getConsoleManager();

IConsole [] consoles = manager.getConsoles();
```

Some consoles will be instances of the `TextConsole` class, for these you can get the text using:

```java
TextConsole textConsole = ... get console

IDocument document = textConsole.getDocument();

String text = document.get();
```

The console manager also lets you set up listeners to be informed changes to consoles. There are also extension points to allow you to hook in to the console system.